# How exclude simple getter and setter from sonar?

Tags: java, sonarqube, getter-setter, metrics

There is the [way](http://skitch-img.s3.amazonaws.com/20100903-ekunteuietuq9j394prku9d37t.jpg) to exclude getter and setters from sonar report. Suppose I have 2 "getters":

```
public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public int getComplexId(){
    int result = 0;
    // some complex calculation there
    return result;
}
```

It is possible to **exclude** getId() and **include** getComplexId() simultaneously? Can Sonar analyze simple return this.id from complex code?

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you want. But since it is not a simple accessor (getter or setter), couldn't you name the method `calculateComplexId()`?

Comment: In my simple example - yes, in the real code no. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use NOPMD comment to avoid Sonar analysis.

```
public int getId(){ // NOPMD
    return this.id;
}

public int getComplexId(){ 
    int result = 0;
    // some complex calculation there
    return result;
}
```

Also you can use //NOSONAR or //CHECKSTYLE:OFF comment. More info in http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-1-12-in-screenshots/

Comment: That is funny, normally Sonar would generate a trailing comment violation for comments on code lines. Not saying that your answer is wrong, just a wierd solution from the Sonar team.

Comment: Very funny. To make code analysis simpler I must add more monkey code with //CHECKSTYLE:OFF and //CHECKSTYLE:ON. But thanks for your answer anyway. :-)

Comment: Isn't Sonar moving away from PMD in the future though?

Answer (score 0):

@Cherry, out of the box SonarQube already behaves as expected : the first method is considered as a getter and not the second one as this method contains some logic.

Comment: Strange, I have sonar see sonar report and it highlightings getters. May be I miss some settings? Or you mean with using [settings](http://skitch-img.s3.amazonaws.com/20100903-ekunteuietuq9j394prku9d37t.jpg) sonar behaves as expected?

Comment: To be exact Cherry, on this provided example, SonarQube reports by default two methods and 0 accessors due to a limitation which is going to be fixed in SonarQube Java version 1.5 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-7). So with version 1.5, the first one will be reported by default as an accessor and the second one always as a method.