# Solve Sonar issue in simple getter and setter methods with Date or List

Tags: java, sonarqube, getter-setter

I write this getter/setter to list from Eclipse source menu:

```
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

And Sonar reporting two issues:

> Return a copy of "date" & Store a copy of "date"

with the explanation

> "Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly"

and a example code:

```
public String [] getStrings() {
    return strings.clone();}

public void setStrings(String [] strings) {
    this.strings = strings.clone();}
```

I think if my Date is null, it will throw a NullPointerException. Then I've changed my code to:

```
public Date getDate() {
    if (this.date != null) {
        return new Date(this.date.getTime());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    if (date != null) {
        this.date = new Date(date.getTime());
    } else {
        this.date = null;
    }
}
```

And now marks other issue:

> "Assigning an Object to null is a code smell. Consider refactoring".

I've searched in internet and set or return a new array is not a solution for me, I want to preserve my list to null if the setter param is null to overwrite an existing previous list.

I've the same problem for List, and I want to return/preserve null instead of a new ArrayList for an empty List. And in this case, the setter marks one more issue:

> "Return an empty collection instead of null.".

What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: You could skip sonar by a placing a simple comment on those methods, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587828/how-exclude-simple-getter-and-setter-from-sonar. As they are getter/setter methods and if you don't have any logic around that need more analysis you should just skip it.

Comment: These are just suggestions that the static code analysis tool is giving you. I think the _defensive copying_ for the date values that you now have there is sufficient. However, I would strongly suggest that you make a habit of returning empty collections instead of `null` ones. It will make client code a lot cleaner. And return an `ImmutableList` if you don't want to allow altering the contents.

Comment: If you *really* wanted to, you probably *could* get rid of the code smell warning by doing `this.date = date != null ? new Date(date.getTime()) : date;`

Comment: can you tell which rule exactly is raising the issue "Assigning an Object to null is a code smell" ? It's showed in the description of the issue in the top right corner and looks like "squid:xxx"

Comment: @MarioSantini I would like to write the correct code and I don't want to hide issues.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Your solution can be a good idea, but for Date?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Your solution will be raise the same issue in the "else" assign for date directly.

Comment: @JaviL OK, good to know. Thought it was worth the try :)

Comment: @TiborBlenessy I don't found the number of squid. I only see this:

Null Assignment  
pmd:NullAssignment
 No tags  Reliability > Data
Assigning a null to a variable (outside of its declaration) is usually bad form. Some times, the assignment is an indication that the programmer doesn't completely understand what is going on in the code. NOTE: This sort of assignment may in rare cases be useful to encourage garbage collection. If that's what you're using it for, by all means, disregard this rule :-)

Comment: @JaviL I agree with you that the purpose should be to write the correct code, but I don't think you should overcomplicated a setter just to be complain with a static software analyzer that could give you a false positive. If you care, you should change the method signature introducing the *final* to assure you have an immutable parameter.

Comment: Move to Java8 where `LocalDate` is immutable, or use `JodaTime` if you have you are forced to use earlier versions of the JDK. For collections `Guava` provides immutable lists, sets, etc

Comment: @JaviL, what does the date model and _why_ can it be `null`? One option would be to use the _null object pattern_ here, but it's hard to give advise without understanding the context.

Comment: @MickMnemonic If the date is null I be sure isn't initialized, but if I creates a new Date() I don't know if is initialized or not.

Comment: @Brad With my Java knowledge i don't understand your solution, I know that I need more time to read about Java8 and immutable data. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Even with Java 8 you will still run into this "mutable" issue with other classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in Java 8 and do not want to handle empty date, then maybe usage of Optional would help you.

Edit: Example of your "POJO" class

```
public class Toto {

    public Optional<Date> myDate;

    public Optional<Date> getMyDate() {
        return this.myDate;
    }

    public void setMyDate(final Date myDate) {
        this.myDate = Optional.ofNullable(myDate);
    }

}
```

Example of code usage:

```
Toto toto = new Toto();
toto.setMyDate(null);
System.out.println("Value is null ? " + toto.getMyDate().isPresent());
System.out.println("Value: " + toto.getMyDate().orElse(new Date()));
```

Try to change the toto.setMyDate(...) with concrete date value to see what happen.

If you don't know what is Optional or how to use it, you can find plenty of examples.

**BUT** : This is only a way to solve your violation issue and i totally agree with Brad's remark, Optional are not intent to be used as a type, but more like a contract for potential empty / null returns.
In general, you should not correct your code in a bad way just to fix a violation, if the violation is not correct. And in your case i think you should just ignore the violation (as most of Sonar's one unfortunatly)

If you really want to use Java 8 and Optional in your code, then you POJO class would be like this (usage of Optional as a contrat on the getter only)

```
public class Toto {


    public Date myDate;

    public Optional<Date> getMyDate() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.myDate);
    }

    public void setMyDate(final Date myDate) {
        this.myDate = myDate;
    }

}
```

This way,

- You bean stay serializable (Optional is not)
- You still enable your "client" code to have the choice on how to behave to empty / null value of your property
- Configure your Sonar violation as a false positive as it is what you want instead of changing your code

Comment: I've insert this setter solution and I think can be correct. In the next Sonar review will check this.

Because I don't understand your getter solution. Is this code out of the getter code? Or must be this?

    public Date getDate() {
        this.date.isPresent();
        this.getDate().orElse(null);
    }

Comment: i've updated my anwser with a better code example usage. Your setter can also accept an Optional (to comply with strict definition of a setter). Just be carefull because depending on your version of SonarQube, rules or not up to date for Java 8.. and so you should redefine or ignore them.

Comment: There are several benefits (at least for me): Optional deal with null check for you in case you don't / forget to do it. This way first time you run your code you will know that you forgot to do it + contract returning Optional clearly means it can be null/empty + you can handle your custom behaviour from client side (default value or exception) : can be useful for some cases.  So no, you don't need to call 'isPresent', you can just call 'orElse() / orThrow()' on your client, which it quite smooth and more readable than if / else / throw code blocks, especially when you chain methods

Answer (score 3):

Generally, while using static analysis tools to verify the code is valuable, you should not blindly fix every warnings which popups on you. You need to analyze the issue which is triggered and check if it really applies in your context.

Now to address the issues you are mentioning

> Return a copy of "date" & Store a copy of "date"

This seems to be valid one. It is good practice to be defensive and not expose mutable state via getters/setters. So creating a defensive copy in getter/setter should be done. This can be done the way you did it, or by using new Java Time API, which provides immutable objects.

> Assigning an Object to null is a code smell. Consider refactoring

IMO dubious one. The issue is raised by PMD plugin (which is the tool analyzing the code, SonarQube is displaying the report). Issue is raised by this rule http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html#NullAssignment , as you can see it is in controversial category. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, and proper action might be to ignore this warning and mark the issue as "won't fix". You can also configure your SonarQube to not use this particular rule in your Quality Profile setting.

> Return an empty collection instead of null.

You did not provide the code which is triggering it, but this seems to be a valid piece of advice. It is generally better to return empty collections rather than nulls.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to explcitly set `null` in your setter, just use the value being passed in like this...

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
    if (date != null) {
        this.date = new Date(date.getTime());
    } else {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Personally I would never allow null values into my Value objects where ever possible, but that is just my opinionated coding style.

My advice to anyone is to prefer immutable value objects where you set all the values in the constructor and don't allow nulls in. This style may not be appropriate for all 3rd party libraries that expect the java bean getter/setters so be aware where it can be used effectively to simplify your code.

**Edit**

If the above code still gives you the warning and you must have the "property is not set yet" functionality, another approach is to define a "null object" like this

```
public static final Date NO_DATE = new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE);

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = (date == null) ? NO_DATE : new Date(date.getTime());
}
```

Users of this class can refer to the NO_DATE object like this, which still makes for readable code

```
if(toto.getDate() != NO_DATE) ...
```

Or encapsulate this into another method so it's used like this

```
if(toto.hasDate()) ...
```

Of course this doens't add much benefit over the Java 8 Optional approach from @kij but it does work with any version of Java

Comment: Like the solution from @RobbyCornelissen, your solution will be raise the same issue in the "else" assign for date directly.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i updated my answer with another approach